# Is there a way to get the headers from Github csv raw data in java?

Tags: java, csv, header

I'm currently trying to extract headers only in Strings.
The below is the method and I'm trying to get the headers from

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv

not the data of the headers.
I'm using Commons-csv library .
I tried some codes that I found in stackoverflow but it prints the values of the header not the header itself.

how should I change my code to extract headers only with List of Strings

```java
   public void fetchVirusData() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
      
        List<LocationStats> newStats=new ArrayList<>();
        HttpClient client=HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request= HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(VIRUS_DATA_URL))
                .build();
 
        HttpResponse<String> httpResponse=client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

       

        StringReader csvBodyReader=new StringReader(httpResponse.body());
        Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(csvBodyReader);

         //The code I found in stackoverflow that can extract headers but won't work
         CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(csvBodyReader, CSVFormat.EXCEL.withFirstRecordAsHeader());
         List<String> headers = parser.getHeaderNames();

         for(String s:headers){
            System.out.println("header test: "+s);
         }
   }
```

Comment: It it is hard to understand what you are asking.  Please explain what you mean by "it prints the values of the header not the header itself".  Maybe show us what it is currently printing, and what you want it to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

Try this

```java
String fileName = "data.csv";
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName ));
// if the first line is the header
String[] header = reader.readNext();
```

Comment: I want the headers... not the value..I mean the column name

Comment: I updated the answer, let me know the result.